# How can I add cell values based on column header?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

A big spreadsheet includes 100 columns, and those need to be condensed down to 10 by adding together the columns.

There is a key, so that all the columns tagged with "1" go to first new column, and so on.
[image: data]

There are n original columns. Each one of those columns has a key (bottom left), and according to that key it must be added to column 1, 2, 3, or 4 of the new table (bottom right).

The real spreadsheet has perhaps 270+ columns and they must be condensed into 10 columns or so for 3000+ ID's where not all ID's have all columns filled.

I thought of looping through the key first, then finding in the original columns each "A", adding them to first column of new table, then doing that through all of them, but I'm not sure how to avoid overwriting old sums with the new ones.

Comment: Are the column headers show your own headers or Excel headers?

Comment: Just curious..Where are columns J and K?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav They are my own, I apologize for the confusion, did not realize they look the exact same.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I forgot J and K come before L.

Comment: Should your example show 1,2,3,4 as the header, not A,B,C,D?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav not necessarily, the 1 2 3 4 are just the "groups" for the columns, the headers for the output table is in a separate table, I will at the end loop through that to change the headers.

Comment: Would a helper column above `vlookup(your header, your header table,2,0)` then pivoting on this not do the trick, so `vlookup("a",a10:a20,2,0)` will show 1 etc,etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with SUMPRODUCT. Actually, you can code it on VBA using this same formula of SUMPRODUCT and pasting values or with Evaluate:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$6=$F14)*$B$2:$M$6*TRANSPOSE(--($B$14:$B$25=G$13)))
```

Depending on your Excel version maybe you need to input the formula as array formula, so instead of normally, type the formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

**UPDATE:** You can also do it with VBA but you need to make some changes to your source file to make it work with **any** dataset of **any** size:

1. Your data must be alone in a worksheet called **DATA**
2. Your keys must be alone in a worksheet called **KEYS**

The code will generate a new worksheet with the grouped data according to keys. It uses same formula than before, but does it everything alone.

[image]

```
Sub TEST()
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngKeys As Range
Dim LR As Long 'last non blank row
Dim LC As Long 'last non blank column
Dim ThisKeys As Variant



Set wk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)) 'add new worksheet for output at end of workbook

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(LR, LC))
    .Range("A2:A" & LR).Copy wk.Range("A2:A" & LR) 'copy names to output
End With



With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KEYS")
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngKeys = .Range("B2:B" & LR)
    .Range("B2:B" & LR).Copy
    wk.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

With wk
    .Range("B2:B" & LR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ThisKeys = .Range("B2:B" & LR).Value
    .Range("B2:B" & LR).Clear
    .Range("B1").Resize(1, UBound(ThisKeys)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisKeys) 'transpose keys to horizontal
    .Range("A1").Value = "Names / Keys"
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range("B2").FormulaArray = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATA!R2C1:R" & rngData.Rows.Count + 1 & "C1=RC1)*DATA!" & rngData.Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & "*TRANSPOSE(--(KEYS!R2C2:R" & rngKeys.Rows.Count + 1 & "C2=R1C)))"
    .Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, LC)).Address), Type:=xlFillDefault 'drag to right
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, LC)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(LR, LC)).Address), Type:=xlFillDefault 'drag to right
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(LR, LC)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(LR, LC)).Value 'paste as values, not formulas
    
End With



Erase ThisKeys
Set rngKeys = Nothing
Set rngData = Nothing
Set wk = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

I uploaded the file with the code so you can check it out: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rc8oOPcqP4HBFEyamku24H9hHRFpncq_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: But how can I do that for the entire spreadsheet? Would I have to enter the formula on every one of the output columns' cells?

Comment: @deepwave43, have a look at the function INDIRECT

Comment: @deepwave43 No, you just type the formula in the top left cell (G14 in the image) and drag to right and then drag to bottom. It takes seconds....

Comment: @deepwave43 I updated the question with a VBA solution that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it as soon as I get home.